# Can't boot into Ubuntu from USB: Software update required, but always fails

Tags: boot, software-installation, usb, mac

I'm trying to boot into Ubuntu from a USB on Mac OS Calatina. Every time I try, I get a message that a software update is required, but the update fails.

Comment: The `update required` message comes from Ubuntu or Mac OS?